# rename all mapped domain logins for instance

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to rename 100+ mapped domain groups in SQL server.

something like this:

```
old:
    DOMAIN\Group01
    DOMAIN\Group02
    DOMAIN\Group03
    DOMAIN\Group04
    DOMAIN\Group05

new:
        DOMAIN\Group01_OLD
        DOMAIN\Group02_OLD
        DOMAIN\Group03_OLD
        DOMAIN\Group04_OLD
        DOMAIN\Group05_OLD
```

Is there a fast way to bulk rename the logins in SQL?

Comment: UPDATE tablename
SET domain += '_OLD'

Comment: Update tablename? Please elaborate, I am not working with any tables as far as I know

Comment: since you tagged this sqlserver. I assumed this was data in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try following.

In SSMS run the script:

```
select
    'alter login ' + quotename(name) + ' with name = ' + quotename(name + '_OLD')
from
    sys.syslogins
where
    name like 'DOMAIN\Group%'
```

Copy results into clipboard and paste into SSMS New Query tab. Check the commands generated and then run.

Comment: Thanks. this is the output of the query:
alter login [DOMAIN\GROUP01] with name = [DOMAIN\GROUP01_OLD], though in the smss console the old value is listed; DOMAIN\GROUP01..

Comment: @doenoe, this script will not run commands automatically, you will have to copy-paste generated commands into new query tab and run them manually (press F5). To run automatically this should be wrapped into cursor + exec dynamic sql.

Comment: Ah I see, this helps out ALOT! Thank you very much!